# Python returning a different variable type depending on which file function is created

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tuples

I have this function bellow, `async def get_all_distinct_identifications()`, that if I create it inside `CarelinePeopleService` class the return of `await CareLinePeopleService().enrolled_people_list_in_care_lines()` function will be a tuple instead of a Pandas `DataFrame` which is what it should truly return. I can even change `CareLinePeopleService()` to self that it still returning tuple instead of a `DataFrame`.

But if I create this function, `async def get_all_distinct_identifications`, in another file it returns what is expected from it, a Pandas Dataframe.

I think that it is something that Python, behind the scenes, is messing up for some reason.

Does anyone knows what is going on?

```
    async def get_all_distinct_identifications(insurer_id, trigger_type, conditional_type, conditionals_fields):
        df_conditionals = await ConditionalsService().get_from_conditional_table(
            insurer_id=insurer_id,
            trigger_type=trigger_type,
            conditional_type=conditional_type,
            fields=conditionals_fields,
            care_lines=[],
        )

        df_of_people_identified = await CareLinePeopleService().enrolled_people_list_in_care_lines(
            df_care_line=df_conditionals[['care_line_id']].drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True),
            identifications=None,
            limit=1000,
            offset=None
        )

        return df_of_people_identified
```

The definition of CareLinePeopleService().enrolled_people_list_in_care_lines is:

```
 async def enrolled_people_list_in_care_lines(self, df_care_line, identifications=None, limit=1000, offset=None):
        if type(offset) == int:
            df_people_identified = await self.get_batch_of_enrolled_people_by_care_line_id(df_care_line, limit, offset)
        elif identifications is not None:
            df_people_identified = await self.get_new_enrolled_people_in_care_lines(identifications)
        else:
            df_people_identified = await self.get_all_enrolled_people_in_care_lines(df_care_line)

        return df_people_identified
```

Definition of all three functions above:

```
    async def get_batch_of_enrolled_people_by_care_line_id(self, df_care_line, limit, offset):
        list_of_care_line_id = list(df_care_line['care_line_id'].drop_duplicates().astype(str))
        query = CareLinePeopleRepository.enrolled_people_list_in_care_lines(
            list_of_care_line_id=list_of_care_line_id,
            limit=limit,
            offset=offset
        )
        df_of_people_identified = await Mysql().execute_to_pd(query)

        return df_of_people_identified

    async def get_new_enrolled_people_in_care_lines(self, identifications):
        list_of_care_line_id = list(identifications['care_line_id'].drop_duplicates().astype(str))
        identifications_list = list(identifications[['person_id', 'care_line_id']].drop_duplicates().itertuples(index=False, name=None))
        query = CareLinePeopleRepository.enrolled_people_list_in_care_lines(
            list_of_care_line_id=list_of_care_line_id,
            identifications_list=identifications_list
        )
        df_of_people_identified = await Mysql().execute_to_pd(query)

        return df_of_people_identified

    async def get_all_enrolled_people_in_care_lines(self, df_care_line):
        list_of_care_line_id = list(df_care_line['care_line_id'].drop_duplicates().astype(str))
        query = CareLinePeopleRepository.enrolled_people_list_in_care_lines(
            list_of_care_line_id=list_of_care_line_id
        )
        df_of_people_identified = await Mysql().execute_to_pd(query)

        return df_of_people_identified
```

Comment: Without seeing the definition of `enrolled_people_list_in_care_lines()`, we can't answer this question.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. I just added to the question the definition of enrolled_people_list_in_care_lines()

Comment: Okay, so now we need to see the definitions of the three function results it can return...

Comment: So I added it, it all return the same Dataframe (diferent data) because it make the same query with diferent paramenters passed. Below it is only MySql query that is the same for all three functions

Answer (score 0):

When you say:

> ...if I create it inside `CarelinePeopleService` class, ...

If that function (`get_all_distinct_identifications`) looks like it currently does, it doesn't have `self` as the first parameter.
Since it's not decorated with something like `@staticmethod`, depending on how it's called (which you don't specify), the parameters may not be what you think they are.
When you call this via an external file (instead of from within the class), you're likely calling it differently, and passing the parameters in correctly.